# How to call a module defined in Angular Element in the secondary project?

Tags: angular, web-component, angular-elements

In my Angular project, I used the http interceptor module as a web component by Angular Element, and finally I built the project and used it as a script in another Angular project.

But the http interceptor structure I defined in the web component does not apply to the secondary project. In fact, the http intercepto module works independently in the first project and does not apply in the second project.

My question is how to use the interceptor module in the web component in the secondary project?

Thanks!